# How can I use a module as a stand-alone CLI and also as a submodule for another module (API)?

Tags: python

I'd like to figure out how to have a module act independently (as CLI) and as a submodule for another module (as API).

Minimal example: http://www.filedropper.com/submoduleconfusion-master

---

For file structure:

- SubmoduleConfusion/

  - mod_a/

    - mod_a.py

Suppose there's some function that's located in `SubmoduleConfusion.mod_a.mod_a` then I'd use `from mod_a.mod_a import f`

---

Since mod_a can also be run as it's own independent module,

For file structure:

- mod_a/

  - mod_a.py

`from mod_a import f`

Comment: When you talk about "submodules", are you referring to git submodules? If so, why did you tag this [tag:python]?

Comment: Git submodules have nothing to do with Python modules, they're completely different concepts. Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @DavidZ I thought a submodule was a module used within a module. So I guess I should say, I'm wanting to use a module I created as a stand-alone and as a submodule.

Comment: That doesn't answer my (and @Dietrich's) question, though. Is this a question about git or Python? In other words, when you say "module" and "submodule", are you using the words in the sense that git uses them, or in the sense that Python uses them?

Comment: @DavidZ Python submodule.

Comment: OK, in that case I suggest removing all mention of git (including "git submodules") from your question. It's just confusing people. You can still link to Github for the sample code, but this seems like a simple enough question to explain that I don't think you really need that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to make the module pip installable (add setup.py outside 1 step up from module path) with an entry point for a console script.

https://github.com/jtara1/misc_scripts/tree/master/misc_scripts/templates

I use this template setup.py and setup.cfg in most of my module I've created. It uses setuptools_scm which will use the version (tag) from git for the project to define the version within the setup.py.

In other words, you need to `git tag 0.1.0` and `git push --tags` before trying to install the module or upload it to be installed.

My setup.py will also infer the name of the module is the same name as the parent directory (github project name)

so the directory should look something like this

my_module

- images
- my_module

  - __main__.py
- setup.py
- setup.cfg
- README.md

name of alias currently defined within setup function within setup.py , might move it to variable later

https://github.com/jtara1/misc_scripts/blob/master/misc_scripts/templates/setup.py#L113